# How to put new line elements in a list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have input like this:
li

```
There
Which
Who
Where
Why
```

Now I want these words to be included in a list. Desired output

```
l = ['There', 'Which', 'Who', 'Where', 'Why']
```

How should I implement this in python?

This is my current code

```
out=[]
buff=[]

for c in li:
    if c == '\n':
        out.append(''.join(buff))
        buff = []
    else:
        buff.append(c)
else:
    if buff:
        out.append(''.join(buff))
print out
```

But I'm getting output to be

```
[u'There']
[u'Which']
[u'Who']
[u'Where']
[u'Why']
```

Instead of what I want

Comment: What is your current code?

Comment: How do you get your output "like this"? Where's your code?

Comment: Please have a look now

Comment: @Alex Can you please show us your set of strings as well? I think there's an easier way to do this.

Comment: It is a long set of code. I'm finally getting the output from that as I showed above. I just need to put into a list

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Just have a look at the question now

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, it should print on a single line instead of multiple.

```
array = ['Who', 'What', 'Where']

print(" ".join(map(str,array)))
```